# python - Can't upload table with schema to postgres using pandas

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy, psql

I am trying to build a collection of tables within a database all owned by a single schema. Here is a simplified example of my problem.

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema
import sqlalchemy as sqla
import pandas as pd

# I have the database 'db' already created and owned by 'user'
db_url = 'postgresql://user:password@host:5432/db'
# Let's connect to it via sqla
conn = sqla.create_engine(db_url)
# My db is currently empty, let's first create a schema and then populate it
conn.execute(CreateSchema('my_schema'))
# Verify the schema has been added to the db
insp = sqla.inspect(conn)
schema_list = insp.get_schema_names() #checking this variable, it has indeed

# I create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,2], 'bar':[3,4]})
```

Now is the confusing part. If I do this:
`df.to_sql('my_table', db_url)`
Then it works fine, I get:

```
db=> \dt
          List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |    Owner    
--------+------+-------+-------------
 public | my_table  | table | user
(1 row)
```

However, if I add schema as a parameter `df.to_sql('my_table', db_url, schema='my_schema')`, the table isn't uploaded I get

```
db=> \dt
No relations found.
```

Why is pd.df.to_sql not working when I specify a schema?

## UPDATE

```
db=> \dt my_schema.*
          List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |    Owner    
--------+------+-------+-------------
 my_schema    | my_table  | table | user
```

This shows that the table is indeed being created and is being attached to the intended schema. However, is it still part of db? Why does it not show up under \dt??

Comment: You're still probably looking in the wrong place: "Whenever the pattern parameter is omitted completely, the \d commands display all objects that are visible in the current schema search path — this is equivalent to using * as the pattern." In other words if you have not updated your `search_path` to include `myschema`, `\dt` will not list the table even if it is there. Have you tried selecting from the table using its qualified name?

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes sorry I meant to delete the previous question

Comment: @IljaEverilä You were right, I had to `SET search_path TO public, my_schema`. If you add it as an answer, I can give you the credit